# Integration of $x^2-2x+4y^2-8y+1=0$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find by integration the area of the subset of $R^2$ bounded by the curve: $x^2-2x+4y^2-8y+1=0$

What I have tried:

1. Re-arrange to find for $y$, I find that $y = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-(x-1)^2}$  when the equation is simplified as $(x-1)^2+4(y-1)^2-2=0$.

From here I'm unsure of how to proceed with integration. I had thought $y$ would take the integral of this form:

$$\int_{-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-(x-1)^2}}^{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2-(x-1)^2}}$$

By trying to define the equation on a unit circle, however I would deeply appreciate your help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region is an ellipse.

$x^2-2x+4y^2-8y+1=0$

$\implies (x-1)^2 + 4 (y-1)^2 = 4$

Please rewrite as,

$\frac{(x-1)^2}{4}+\frac{(y-1)^2}{1}=1$

The are of ellipse $\displaystyle \frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2} = 1$ is given by $ \pi a b$. So the area is $ 2 \pi$. To find area using integration, please use the change of variable as,

$X = \frac{x- 1}{2}, Y = y - 1$

Jacobian of transformation is $|J| = 2$ and the transformed region is $X^2 + Y^2 = 1$ which is a unit circle.

So the area of the region in polar coordinates is,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 |J| ~ r ~ dr ~  d\theta$

Comment: How did you get $2$ for the jacobian? I seem to get $\frac{1}{2}$ unless I am approaching it incorrectly. Did you take the jacobian of the $rsin(\theta)$ and $rcos(\theta)$ functions, or directly from $X$ or $Y$?

Comment: @Stackcans  it should be the same either way. What you found is not $|J|$ but probably $ |J^{-1}|$. Did you change to express $x = 2X + 1, y = Y + 1$ and then found the jacobian? Otherwise you will get $ |J^{-1}|$

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out and the detailed solution; I took the jacobian in respect to $X$ and $Y$, rather than $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

We can rearrange the equation into $(x-1)^2+4(y-1)^2=4$ so we know this is a translated ellipse. This means that we might want to try a substitution such as $x=2r\cos\theta,\ y=r\sin\theta$ except the '$-1$' in the brackets are a bit annoying.

This is fine however, because we only want the area, so we can translate the curve by $-1\choose-1$ and then the substitution works nicely:
\begin{align}
4r^2\cos^2\theta+4r^2\sin^2\theta&=4\\
\implies r^2&=1
\end{align}
Then making this transformation, we end up with the integral:
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{1}2r\ drd\theta
\end{align}

Comment: Why are your upper bounds of the integral for $dr$ different to the first post?

Comment: I had a wrong number earlier on, I have changed it now